# Travis-cli - error in build commits not synchronised.. How to reset Travis account?

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, nvm

Got this error during travis-cli builds ... 
I checked the commit numbers ( Travis & Github ) they are not synchronised .. I hit the button (sync' but same issue no synchro ..

Is there a way to delete then reset my Tavis account ?

```
    ......
    Preparing to unpack .../google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking google-chrome-stable (62.0.3202.89-1) over (60.0.3112.113-1) ...
    Setting up google-chrome-stable (62.0.3202.89-1) ...
    Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
    travis_fold:end:install_chrome
    [0K$ export PATH=./node_modules/.bin:$PATH
    [33;1mUpdating nvm[0m
    travis_fold:start:nvm.install
    [0Ktravis_time:start:02fde630
    [0K$ nvm install 8.5.1
    Version '8.5.1' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.

        travis_time:end:02fde630:start=1510438925841600553,finish=1510438926083046237,duration=241445684
    [0K[31;1mFailed to install 8.5.1. Remote repository may not be reachable.[0m
    Using locally available version 8.5.1, if applicable.
    $ nvm use 8.5.1
    N/A: version "8.5.1 -> N/A" is not yet installed.

    You need to run "nvm install 8.5.1" to install it before using it.
    [31;1mUnable to use 8.5.1[0m

    [31;1mThe command "false" failed and exited with 1 during .[0m

    Your build has been stopped.
```

**.travis.ylml**

```
    language: node_js
    node_js:
      - "8.9.1"
    sudo: false
    dist: trusty
    addons:
      chrome: stable
    cache:
      yarn: true
      directories:
        - node_modules
    install:
      - yarn
    script:
      - yarn test
```

Comment: Can you post your travis.yml

Comment: added in the question..  it's updated to node 8.9.1 , but I was using 8.5.1 in previous tests... I guess there is something wrong with the commits #... will check it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrong commit sync between Travis & Github ... resolved by merging & rebase the Github commits